# Eagles and Airplanes

Tags: sources-mekorot, parashas-yisro

The verse says ([Exodus 19:4](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Exodus.19?vhe=Tanach_with_Ta%27amei_Hamikra&lang=bi&aliyot=0)):

> אַתֶּ֣ם רְאִיתֶ֔ם אֲשֶׁ֥ר עָשִׂ֖יתִי לְמִצְרָ֑יִם **וָאֶשָּׂ֤א אֶתְכֶם֙ עַל־כַּנְפֵ֣י נְשָׁרִ֔ים** וָאָבִ֥א אֶתְכֶ֖ם אֵלָֽי׃
>
> ‘You have seen what I did to the Egyptians, **how I bore you on eagles’ wings** and brought you to Me.

Does anyone know of a source that talks about this verse referring to an airplane?

Comment: Besides the wikipedia page talking about the 1950 operation?

Comment: Besides for the Yemeni Aliyah operation @rosends is referring to, I believe Ethiopian Jews, having never seen planes before, thought they were riding giant birds during their respective Aliyah operations. However, no source that I know translates this verse as airplanes. At most, Maimonides refers to the notion of an iron ship floating in the sky as fantasy, a figment of the imagination.

Comment: @robev How would it occur through airplanes? Are you expressing a metaphor?

Comment: @TurkHill does anyone say that "on the wings of eagles" is _not_ a metaphor?

Comment: @Heshy Good point.

Comment: The verse is in the past tense, about how they left Egypt. It was clearly a metaphor for the majesty and security they experienced. To quote Rabbi Moshe Hauer, "our approach should be idiomatic, not idiotic."

Answer (score 3):

[R. Yitzchak Barda](https://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%99%D7%A6%D7%97%D7%A7_%D7%91%D7%A8%D7%93%D7%90) in Shu"t Yitzchak Yeranen 7:204 does mention that the "wings of eagles" may refer to airplanes. He notes that it is not really possible to sit on eagles without falling off, and therefore it might mean airplanes, flying beds, flying carpets, flying staffs, etc.

He then strengthens the idea that it is specifically airplanes from the fact that "wings of eagles" refers to the future redemption as well, and we see that much of the in-gathering of the exile has occurred via airplanes. He further notes that airplanes actually have wings even though they could have been made without wings like missiles (consult your local engineer for whether this is scientifically accurate), and this shows that Heaven guided man's creation of airplanes.

> ובפרט שלשון על כנפי נשרים אינו מורה על מציאות כפשוטו אלא לשון מושאל כי איך אפשר לישב על כנפי נשרים בלי ליפול ובפרט באשר ידאה הנשר אלא על כרחנו כוונת כנפי נשרים כמו כאן במטוס או בדמיון המטה של מהרח"ו זיע"א בכתי"ק בס' אלקימיה וממילא לשון כנפי נשרים הוא לשון מושאל ואפשר ע"י שם כמ"ש התוספות שם ואפשר על מקל ואפשר ע"י מחצלת כמעשה ר"ש אביחצירא זיע"א ואפשר ע"י מטוסים כהיום ואני מחדש בס"ד שכוונתו כמעט ממש כמו על מטוס והראיה מהעתיד שגם נאמר שם על כנפי נשרים ונעשה הקיבוץ גלויות עד היום עם בנפי הנשרים המושאל שהוא אוירונים ומטוסים וסיבה לדבר כי לשון בנפי הנשרים המושאל שהוא אוירונים ומטוסים וסיבה לדבר כי לשון כנפי מורה על המטוסים שיש להם כנפיים שהרי יכלו לעשות מטוסים בלי כנפיים כמו טילים ישרים אבל מה יעשו הבריות והרי אין אדם נוקף אצבע מלמטה אלא א"ב נגזר עליו מלמעלה ומשמים גזרו בבחינת כי הוא אמר כנפי נשרים ויהי הוא צוה ויעמוד ולא בטילים

Comment: If Manna fell from shamayim, the yam suf split, the amud esh and Annan traveled with the Jews, Why can't eagles carry them without them falling off?